# Generator invalidated when wrapped inside IteratorIterator

Tags: php, iterator, generator

In PHP 5.6 to 7.1 a Generator instance seems to be invalidated when being wrapped inside an `IteratorIterator` class:

```
<?php
function natural_numbers()
{
    for ($i = 1; ; $i++) {
        yield $i;
    }
}

$generator = natural_numbers();
var_dump($generator->valid());
var_dump($generator->current());

$wrap = new IteratorIterator(natural_numbers());
var_dump($wrap->valid());
var_dump($wrap->current());

$wrap->next();
var_dump($wrap->valid());
var_dump($wrap->current());
```

Remarkably the above outputs for all PHP versions

```
bool(true)
int(1)

bool(false)
NULL

bool(true)
int(2)
```

In HHVM on the other hand I get

```
bool(true)
int(1)

bool(true)
NULL

bool(true)
int(2)
```

which is weird as well... The iterator is valid but its current value is `null`.

Is this a bug in PHP or is this expected and documented behaviour? I'm confused.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the value in wrapping a Generator inside an IteratorIterator, but it does seem to be a bug with the initialisation of the IteratorIterator

Comment: The value is that you can add (lazy) collection helper methods `take(int $n)` and `filter(callable $f)` and the like. Extending `IteratorIterator` reduces boilerplate

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out too, thx. The problem is however that generators throw when calling `rewind` after the first `next()` call. So that would make it impossible to add say a `skip(int)` or `slice(int)` helper function which consumes a couple items from the generator and return the remaining generator wrapped in IteratorIterator.

Comment: @Paul The trouble is that you can't rewind a Generator (sad)... I'm currently trying to figure out how to access the Generator internals to see if I can find a way to do just that

Comment: Of course the easiest way to solve this problem is to explicitly write a decorator for an iterator implementing the Iterator interface. But then again you can't use other SPL iterators like LimitIterator and FilterIterator because they extend IteratorIterator as well. Shame :(

Comment: @PaulCrovella see my comment: there are useful cases where you wrap a running generator in an IteratorIterator instance, so rewinding or reinstanciating won't cut it and is often impossible if you want an iterator over a subset of a generator.

Comment: Alright, maybe I've understood IteratorIterator incorrectly. I'll just use my own decorator then and stop using SPL iterators.